# Avoiding bidirectional filter for a matrix report

Tags: powerbi, dax, filtering, database-schema

I am learning how to use Power BI and one of the repeating pro tips is to avoid bidirectional filtering. I have a model with the following structure:

Table 1 (Course names):

- Course ID
- Course name

Sample data:

```
C1  Python
C2  Calculus
C3  Algebra
```

Table 2 (Course category):

- Course Id
- Course category

Sample data:

```
C1  CS
C2  Math
C3  Math
```

Table 3 (Course lecturers):

- Lecturer name
- Course Id

Sample data:

```
L1  C1
L2  C1
L1  C2
L3  C2
L3  C3
```

There may be multiple courses in a single category and multiple lecturers in a single course.

I would like to generate a matrix report where the rows are by lecturer name, the columns are by category, and the value is the distinctcount of courses. In other words, I would like to understand how many courses from each category each lecturer teaches. For the given sample data I would expect the following result:

```
    CS  Math
L1  1   1
L2  1   0
L3  0   2
```

The only way I got this working was to define the relationship between the tables as bidirectional. Is there an alternative schema that avoids this?

Comment: Where's your sample date?

Comment: I edited the question to include sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice is correct - avoid bi-directional filtering for numerous reasons. Where you need to propagate a relationship, you can turn on bi-directional filtering for a single measure as required using CROSSFILTER().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/crossfilter-function

Comment: The advice is correct - but not in all cases. Here the OP has one-to-one relations only.

Comment: Agreed for one-to-one relationships where there is no other choice. If you have one-to-one, there is usually a case for just consolidating the tables.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, since CROSSFILTER does establish a (unnecessary) bi-directional relationship, although temporarily only.

Comment: The reason to avoid bi-directional filters is for performance and model ambiguity. It is OK to enable bi-directional filters using crossfilter on a case-by-case basis. You can also do the same using treatas to create a temp virtual relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Bi-directional relations are only "problematic" in one-to-many relations. One-to-one relations are always bi-directional.

But you have such a one-to-many relation between Table 1 and Table 3. Table 1 can filter Table 3, but not vice versa. However, **you don't need to filter Table 1**, since you have the required Course ID's already in Table 3. And Table 2 can still filter Table 3 as this is following just the direction arrows.

**You don't need any bi-directional relations or CROSSFILTER() to solve this problem!**

[image]

In case you "need" the zeros in the matrix use this measure

```
Distinct Courses = 
VAR _count = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table 3'[Course ID])
RETURN
    IF(ISBLANK(_count), 0, _count )
```

Of cause you can get the same result with a temporary bi-directional relation:

```
Distinct Courses with Crossfilter = 
VAR _count =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Table 1'[Course ID]),
        CROSSFILTER(
            'Table 1'[Course ID],
            'Table 3'[Course ID], 
            Both)
    )
RETURN
    IF(ISBLANK(_count), 0, _count)
```

Comment: This is true for the relationship between the two first tables, but not for the relationship between the courses and lecturers. I added sample data to clarify this point.

Comment: You can see that there are multiple rows for the same course in the lecturers' table.

Comment: @Shaharg I updated my answer due to the updated question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my model, I tried to simplify my schema, and hence Table 3 has the course ID. In my actual schema, I have another table between Table 1 and Table 3 which has the course subcategory and table 3 only has the subcategory and category. So in practice, I really needed some way of filtering table 3 based on the fact table. This is why I marked the other answer as correct, as it solved my actual problem.

Comment: Fair enough. But visitors of this post should be aware that your choice has nothing to do with your actual question.