# Aggregating a dimension table by fact table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, dax, filtering, powerbi-desktop

I have a hierarchy of three PowerBI tables

Courses:

| Course ID | Course credits |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 2 |
| C2 | 3 |

Practical Courses:

| Practical Course ID | Course ID | Year | Number of Students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1.22 | C1 | 2022 | 10 |
| C1.23 | C1 | 2023 | 15 |
| C2.21 | C2 | 2021 | 17 |

Practical course lecturers:

| Lecturer name | Practical Course ID |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | C1.22 |
| Jack | C1.23 |
| Jill | C1.22 |
| Jill | C2.21 |

Note that one course may have multiple practical courses and that one practical course may have multiple lecturers.

I would like to find the total number of credits and students for each lecturer. For the given sample data, I would like to get the following results

| Lecturer name | Credits | Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 4 | 25 |
| Jill | 5 | 27 |

The problem is that the filters go the "wrong" way. I somehow need to aggregate the metadata filtered by the fact table value.

Is there a simple way of doing this without resorting to bidirectional filters? This is a general problem I encounter in multiple forms.

Edit: I was asked whether the following thread answers my question [Avoiding bidirectional filter for a matrix report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016170/avoiding-bidirectional-filter-for-a-matrix-report/75016511#75016511)

There are two answers that are suggested there:

1. Use a cross-filter to define an ad-hoc filter for this specific query.
2. Use a common field that appears in the fact table.

I don't see how these answers apply to this question. In particular, it seems cumbersome to set two cross-filters to connect the fact table with the top-level table (There may be multiple levels). The second suggestion isn't relevant since there is no common field between the first and third tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding bidirectional filter for a matrix report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016170/avoiding-bidirectional-filter-for-a-matrix-report)

Comment: No (Actually I asked that question too). There are two answers that are suggested there:

1. Use a cross filter to define an ad-hoc filter for this specific query.
2. Use a common field that appears in the fact table. 

I don't see how these answers apply to this question. In particular, it seems cumbersome to set two cross-filters to connect the fact table with the top-level table (There may be multiple levels). The second suggestion isn't relevant since there is no common field between the first and third tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@peter is correct. I'll make the following points.

1. You have a snowflake schema. That is why " it seems cumbersome to set two cross-filters to connect the fact table with the top-level table"
2. Your sample data doesn't match your results. I have corrected this in my example below.

[image]

3. Here is how you achieve your desired result.

[image]

[image]

Measure 1:

```
Students = CALCULATE( SUM('Practical Courses'[Number of Students]),  CROSSFILTER('Practical Courses'[Practical Course ID] , 'Practical Course Lecturers'[Practical Course ID], Both))
```

Measure 2:

```
Credits = SUMX('Practical Course Lecturers', CALCULATE(SUM(Courses[Course credits]),  CROSSFILTER('Practical Courses'[Practical Course ID] , 'Practical Course Lecturers'[Practical Course ID], Both),CROSSFILTER(Courses[Course ID], 'Practical Courses'[Course ID], Both) ))
```

There are 3 ways to aggregate a dimension from a fact if you don't use bi-directional filters.

1. Pass whole fact table as a filter in Calculate (not good)
2. Use cross filter in calculate
3. Use TREATAS()

Comment: Regarding your first point, does this imply that a snowflake schema is not recommended? From what I understand, you are saying that every time I have a snowflake schema, I would need to add cross-references to my queries to propagate the filter from fact to lookups.

Comment: PBI works best with a star schema. PBI has a semantic data model and you can easily reshape your data in PQ or using calculated tables. You can use a snowflake but it comes with drawbacks like the ones you're encountering. Have a read here from the experts: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-importance-of-star-schemas-in-power-bi/